# Protractor + AngularJS + Jasmine get output results on xml file

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, protractor

I'm trying to export protractor results to xml files,
i found this great link on web: https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/60

After running : npm install jasmine-reporters

i added the following lines to my protracotr config file:

```
require('jasmine-reporters');

jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new jasmine.JUnitXmlReporter(
    'C:\temp\test', true, true));
```

and i get the following error:

> > > jasmine.console_reporter.js:2
> > >       if (! jasmine) {
> > >       ^
> > >       ReferenceError: jasmine is not defined

i attached here my config file, please advise what am i doing wrong, and how can i fix this:

```
require('jasmine-reporters');

jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new jasmine.JUnitXmlReporter(
    'C:\temp\test', true, true));

// An example configuration file.
exports.config = {
    seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
    chromeOnly: true,

  capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome'
  },

  specs: ['../test/protractor/publisher_list_e2e.js'],
    allScriptsTimeout: 60000,
  // Options to be passed to Jasmine-node.

  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    showColors: true,
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000
  }

};
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have to change your config file so it looks like this:

```
// An example configuration file.
exports.config = {
  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
  chromeOnly: true,

  capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome'
  },

  specs: ['../test/protractor/publisher_list_e2e.js'],
  allScriptsTimeout: 60000,

  // Options to be passed to Jasmine-node.
  onPrepare: function() {      
    require('jasmine-reporters');
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(
      new jasmine.JUnitXmlReporter(null, true, true, '<path to directory>')
    );
  },

  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    showColors: true,
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000
  }
};
```

The whole `jasmine-reports` feature has to be done in the `onPrepare` statement since `jasmine` is required the only way that's guaranteed is within the `onPrepare` function.

And  will be based from the root folder of your project.

Comment: I am trying to generate report in `/report` directory, so I used `new jasmine.JUnitXmlReporter(null, true, true, './report')` But it still generates xml report in root folder of project. I am using ubuntu.Any suggestion?

Comment: By default JUnitXmlReporter uses the root folder of your project as the base so you have to work from there. I don't think it recognizes the './' (current directory syntax) so you'd have to manually input it.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use html screenshot reporter for protractor angularjs tests.

https://github.com/jintoppy/protractor-html-screenshot-reporter

Comment: this is not properly supported they don't answer for weeks to their issues