# Protractor/Jasmine do not create folder for xunit file when it does not exist

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner, protractor

I have a protractor instance that tests my app.

The following is my config for where the jasmine.JUnitXmlReporter should write the results file.

```
onPrepare: function () {
        require('jasmine-reporters');
        var capsPromise = browser.getCapabilities();
        capsPromise.then(function (caps) {
            var browserName = caps.caps_.browserName.toUpperCase();
            var browserVersion = caps.caps_.version;
            var prePendStr = browserName + '-' + browserVersion + '-';
            jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new jasmine.JUnitXmlReporter('test-results/protractor/', true, true, prePendStr));
        });
    },...
```

This presents a bit of an interesting challenge for git, because it won't track a folder unless there is a file in it.  Which means that when my CI server is working on this, the file won't get written unless I put some other dummy file there.

I've played with the permissions on the folders, and that doesn't help.  Is there something I'm doing wrong here?  Running karma unit tests doesn't exhibit this same problem, e.g.:

```
junitReporter: {
            outputFile: 'test-results/unit/results.xml',
            suite: ''
        },
```

Answer (score 3):

This is how JUnitXmlReporter is made. You can see it's source code [here](https://github.com/larrymyers/jasmine-reporters/blob/master/src/jasmine.junit_reporter.js).
You can use [File System module](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html) here to make the folder needed before setting up the `JUnitXmlReporter`

```
var fs = require('fs')
fs.mkdirSync('unit');
fs.mkdirSync('unit/test-results');
jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new jasmine.JUnitXmlReporter('test-results/protractor/'..
```

There is also a [`mkdirp`](https://www.npmjs.org/package/mkdirp) module in NPM  for avoiding errors when folder already is there.

Comment: I see, makes sense that I have all the goodness of node available to do things like this.  The light just went on over my head, that's basically the point of the onPrepare- to prepare everything you need for the tests, naturally...  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

My solution ended up being a combination of what @Mohsen suggest above and [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23216630/protractor-angularjs-jasmine-get-output-results-on-xml-file).

Instead of using synchronous file processing I opted to use Q to turn the mkdir calls into promises.  Additionally, the capsPromise appends the browser version to the output file for extra information.

```
onPrepare: function () {
        require('jasmine-reporters');
        var fs = require('fs');
        var Q = require('q');

        var mkdir = Q.denodeify(fs.mkdir);
        mkdir('test/test-results')
            .then(function(data) {
                mkdir('test/test-results/protractor')
                    .then(function(data) {
                        var capsPromise = browser.getCapabilities();
                        capsPromise.then(function (caps) {
                            var browserName = caps.caps_.browserName.toUpperCase();
                            var browserVersion = caps.caps_.version;
                            var prePendStr = browserName + '-' + browserVersion + '-';
                            jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new jasmine.JUnitXmlReporter('test/test-results/protractor/', true, true, prePendStr));
                        });
                    })
                    .fail(function(err) {
                        console.err('Error creating directory ' + err);
                    })
            })
            .fail(function(err) {
                console.err('Error creating directory ' + err);
            });
    },
```